# How can I avoid passing null parameters to a function with multiple optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, web

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
function f(requiredParamA, requiredParamB, optionalObjectParamA, optionalObjectParamB) {
    optionalObjectParamA = optionalObjectParamA || {};
    optionalObjectParamB = optionalObjectParamB || {};

    // rest of the function
}
```

Say I want to call `f` with a value for the `optionalObjectParamB`, but not for `optionalObjectParamA`. I could do this:

```
f("john", 100, null, {vegatarian: true});
```

But that makes for an ugly API.
Is there any other option? How should I design the function and how should I call it?

Comment: if oA expects a number and oB expects a string, you can sniff the type of the argument to oA if oB is undefined, which will let you decide if the value should be re-assigned as oB or kept as oA. you can do that for any type, or with objects, a smoking gun prop/value that one expectation has that the other doesn't.

Comment: you can also use an options object argument, like jquery's ajax does, where only the properties you need to adjust have to be filled-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an object rather than parameters.  Then you can have unlimited optional parameters without blowing up your parameter list.

```
function f(requiredParamA, requiredParamB, context) {
    var optional = context || {};
    // handle optional.optionalObjectParamA..
    // handle optional.optionalObjectParamB..
}
```

Comment: Yes, and this way lets you conveniently have a "defaults" object, which has all the option settings to use when they are not specified, as in `options = $.extend({}, defaults, options)`, or something equivalent.

Comment: I'd take it a step further and make ALL params part of the options object and throw an error if they are missing.